# CSS & Images Don't Load on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, firefox-addon

website moonrun.com
on Chrome, Edge & Safari browsers all loads well
but on Firefox both mac & mobile, the website just loads without CSS & images.

I can't find the reason for this behavior

on the developer console appear "style sheet could not be loaded"

Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with 'Active mixed content delivered via HTTP. Firefox will block it by default. Check the link below at MDN. This will help you fix the problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: all CSS URLS are in HTTPS, so i don't think this is the issue. if it was the issue, also on chrome and ie the website would crash.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it crashed on firefox is because of :
The rel value preload is not supported in Firefox and is only supported by Google Chrome. Therefore, Firefox can't see the CSS file, and the elements aren't being styled correctly.

changed from:

{{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

to
{{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

After this change the website return to work.